# Removing non-numeric rows in a Pandas data frame mid-chain

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column called EID. It is mostly integers but there are a few non-numeric values in the column. I'm trying to remove them in the middle of a function chain.

Here are some of the errors I get in the middle of my debugging session:

```
(Pdb) df.dropna(subset=['EID']).query('EID.str.isnumeric()')
*** ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
(Pdb) df.dropna(subset=['EID']).query('EID.str.isdigit()')
*** ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

I even tried creating a new column:

```
(Pdb) df.dropna(subset=['EID']).assign(isnum = lambda x: x.EID.str.isdigit())
```

but this new column is nothing but `NaN`.

How can I remove the rows where this column is non-numeric in the middle of a chain?

Edit: Sample dataset

input:

| EID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Madsen,Gunnar |
| ret | Greene,Richard |
| 465 | Stull,Matthew |

Desired output:

| EID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Madsen,Gunnar |
| 465 | Stull,Matthew |

Comment: Can you add some mock data with expected outputs to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with a callable that combines [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
out = df.loc[lambda d: pd.to_numeric(d['EID'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Or, if you also want to take the opportunity to convert EID to numeric, [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
out = (df.assign(EID=lambda d: pd.to_numeric(d['EID'], errors='coerce'))
         .dropna(subset=['EID']).convert_dtypes()
       )
```

Output:

```
   EID           Name
0  123  Madsen,Gunnar
2  465  Stull,Matthew
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out what is happening without a reproducible dataframe, but this may help:

```
df['EID'][df['EID'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))]
```

This create a series containing all the `int`s from the column `EID`.